# How would one get the dialogue from a GMap embed centered?

Tags: html, google-maps

- When I embed a Google Map right from Google Map's Embed feature:
  [gmap on page load with info dialogue not centered by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wukja.png)
- Found this on another site where the dialogue shows up in the screen:
  [gmap on page load with info dialogue centered by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw6aY.png)

So the question is- how do I make the dialogue appear in full by default(Like in the second image)? It looks much better this way.

Comment: Posting a link to the website is more useful, we can view the source for a definitive answer. I'm guessing it's a manual setCenter(), because I see it's not exactly cleared (the "Map" button covers the top right portion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the view as you want it on the Google Maps site. ie so the marker is on the appriate part of the screen.

Then get your embed code.

(can also alter the center by playing with the values of the ll= param in the code)

(also this question is not actully about the API!)